# Live Streaming and Recording Simultaneously

Tags: video, live, streaming, camera

I will explain my situation first.  I am getting married in two months and have many family members that are in bad health.  They want to make the wedding, but just cant.  We had the idea of streaming the wedding over Skype, etc.  We had already planned on having a basic camcorder (non-professional) to record the wedding.

My question is, can we record the wedding and stream the video simultaneously using the same camcorder?  Or will we need a separate camcorder for each?

I'd love to make this possible without costing too much.

Answer (score 1):

personally I think ustream or the like would be easier. assuming you dont mind the possibility of someone else watching

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward - but you will need to install a 3rd party app to do it. I know of a couple:

- [Supertintin](http://shop.skype.com/apps/Call-recording-audio-video/SuperTintin-Video-Call-Recorder.html)
- [Vodburner](http://www.vodburner.com/)
- [Evaer](http://www.evaer.com/)
- Pamela
- imCapture for Skype

These will record the entire call to disk.